# Saving checkbox state using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, eclipse

how do i save a checkbox state in activity B so that when i go back to activity A , it will show an appropriate response?

I am trying to make a function such that when a checkbox state in Activity B is checked , it will go back to A and play music , and this preference will be saved so that when the app is killed and relaunched , the preference stays.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a boolean in SharedPreferences. It's clearly explained here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

On Activity B you need to set preference depends on the `CheckBox` state

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("checked", isChecked);
        editor.commit();
    }
});
```

On Activity A you need to get the preference value as follow

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isChecked = sharedPref.getBoolean("checked", false); // false if it's not exist
```

Comment: How would that work in a RecyclerView with lots of checkboxes?

Comment: You can just set different key for each item. For example, you can use the item position as follow > editor.putBoolean("checked" + position, isChecked); and same thing when you get the value

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in your activity B and override onSharedPreferenceChanged method

Here's my code

```
@Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences preferences,String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        checkbox = preferences.getBoolean("checkbox", false);

       if(checkbox){

               //Do your stuff here like playing music

                Log.d("checkbox", "check enabled");
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);

                startActivity(myIntent);


             }
```